# How to join two endpoints of different paths in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How to join two endpoints of different paths in Illustrator?

It is said in manual, that points should be selected first, but I can't select them, since they are not on the same path.

I can select two paths in total, but once I start selecting nodes, only one path remains selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use *SHIFT* + *click*.

1. Select the first point with a simple mouse-click.
2. Use the *SHIFT* key with a mouse-click to select the second point on the other path.

That way, you can select multiple points on the same and on different paths.